# cmake: add directory to be searched for header files

Tags: c++, cmake, arduino

I am writing c++ code to run tests on an arduino project I've written. In order to run it, I need it to include mockups of a couple libraries (the original libraries don't work in c++). The mockups are in my src directory, along with the tests in main.cpp. The files that rely on the mockups are in the parent directory of src, and I cannot modify them to refer to src without breaking their ability to run when uploaded to an arduino. I also cannot add the mockups or main.cpp to the parent directory, as this would interfere with the operation of the arduino code.

So, I need to add the child directory with the mockups to the directories that are searched when compiling the files in the parent directory.

Directory Outline:

```
parent
    forTest.h
    forTest.cpp
    src
        parson.h
        parson.c
        String.h
        String.cpp
        main.cpp
        CMakeLists.txt
    build
```

In this case, main.cpp has "#include ../forTest.cpp", and forTest.cpp has "#include parson.h" and "#include String.h"

I am currently running the following code in CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project(makeTest)

include_directories(../ )

set (makeTest_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (makeTest_VERSION_MINOR 0)

add_executable(makeTest main.cpp ../forTest.cpp String.cpp parson.c)
```

I then build it in the build directory from the command line with

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../src
make
```

The cmake command resolves successfully, but the make command hits "fatal error: parson.h not found" when building forTest.cpp

How can I resolve this?

edit: my apologies if this has an obvious answer, I'm very new to Cmake

edit the second: using the changes suggested by Gergely Nyiri and changing #include to #include "/usr/include/string.h" resolves several errors, but introduces a new error : "implicit instantiation of undefined template" during the make step.

It refers to the following code in by string.h mockup file:

```
#ifndef STRING_H
#define STRING_H

#include "/usr/include/string.h"
using namespace std;

class String {
private:
    std::string thisString;
    char chars[];
...
#endif
```

which returns the error:

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:61:
/Users/douglas/Desktop/parts/makeHolder/testMake/src/string.h:9:14: error: 
implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_string<char,
  std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'
    std::string thisString;
```

This is followed by:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:193:32: note: 
    template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would propose to put CMakeLists.txt in your source root. Then:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project(makeTest)

include_directories(src)

set (makeTest_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (makeTest_VERSION_MINOR 0)

add_executable(makeTest src/main.cpp forTest.cpp src/String.cpp src/parson.c)
```

Configure & build:

```
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

Even better if you use **target_include_directories** instead of include_directories:

```
..
add_executable(makeTest src/main.cpp forTest.cpp src/String.cpp src/parson.c)
target_include_directories(makeTest PRIVATE src)
```

Comment: I tried this, and it does resolve the issue I was having with finding the files. Unfortunately, it also lists about 20 errors such as: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:82:9: error: 
      no member named 'strchr' in the global namespace
using ::strchr;

From what I can tell, it sounds like cmake is including string.h from kernel instead of from standard. Is this normal?

Comment: How do you include string.h? In cpp you should include <cstring> and use std::strchr ...

Comment: I'm just using 
    #include <string.h>
    using namespace std
at the top of the file. 
I'm not actually using the missing members like strchr anywhere in my file, which is why I think cmake is including a file from the wrong place, leaving it with a lot of functions that are missing the file they're defined in

Comment: I was able to resolve the 20 errors by changing #include <string.h> to #include "/usr/include/string.h". That results in a new error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>

This refers to a line where I declare "std::string thisString;"

and it says template is declared here
"_LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_string"

Comment: Accepting this as an answer since it resolves the initial problem, and I think the other problems that have come up are separate issues.